# How could I run tensorflow on windows 10? I have the gpu Geforce gtx 1650. Can I run tensorflow on it? if yes, then how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to do some ML on my computer with Python, I'm facing problem with the installation of tensorflow and I found that tensorflow could work with GPU, which is CUDA enabled. I've got a GPU Geforce gtx 1650, will tensorflow work on that.

If yes, then, how could I do so?

Comment: I would download an Ubuntu ISO and learn to dual boot. Or you can get a separate SSD to install Ubuntu on.

Comment: "See [the GPU guide for CUDA®-enabled cards](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)."

Answer (score 2):

After opening the command prompt in administrator mode,the installation command for Tensorflow with GPU support is as follows:

```
    pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

To check if tensorflow has been successfully installed use command:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

To test CUDA support for your Tensorflow installation, you can run the following command in the shell:

```
    tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

[Warning: if a non-GPU version of the package is installed, the function would also return False. Use this command to validate if TensorFlow was build with CUDA support.]

Finally, to confirm that the GPU is available to Tensorflow, you can test using a built-in utility function in TensorFlow as shown below:

```
    tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Install tensorflow-gpu to do computations on GPU. You can use the code below to check whether your GPU is being used by tensorflow.

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available(
cuda_only=False,
min_cuda_compute_capability=None
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for installation of tensorflow:

1. Download and install the Visual Studio.
2. Install CUDA 10.1
3. Add lib, include and extras/lib64 directory to the PATH variable.
4. Install cuDNN
5. Install tensorflow by `pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if you can.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
Tensorflow clearly mentions the list of supported architectures and the 1650 sadly doesn't belong to the list. Check the "cuda enabled gpu cards" link on the website above.